# Soap Curl request error - 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, curl, soap

I am making soap curl request and here is the code:

```
$headers = array(             
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"", 
    "Accept: text/xml", 
    "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
    "Pragma: no-cache", 
    "SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/Save_ExMsgInfo2\"", 
    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
); 

$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://xxx.yyy.com:517/zzz.asmx" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);


if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{                
    $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($soap_do);
    return $err;
}
else
{
    curl_close($ch); 
    return 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```

But getting below error

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2020 16:42:35 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Any soln?

Comment: Your code seems okay to me. Usually, HTTP 400 is returned when the API receives a request somewhat different than what it expects. So, my suspicion would be on the XML `$xml_post_string` that you are sending. If you haven't already, check the SOAP API WSDL file. Use Chrome plugin called 'Wizdler' to make a request from the browser with the help of the API WSDL.

Comment: Okay Thanks @SohelAman. Let me check